# Time Series analysis for categorical variables

Tags: time-series, categorical-data

Have a question on running time series model. I have 50 categorical variables for 56 months and 1 continuous variable(target). can I run ARIMA model/not for this kind of data?If so how should I go about?If not what other model should I consider?

Have attached a screen shot for better understanding of my question.please help me out[image: Screen Shot Of Data]

Comment: This seems like a good question to me.  Did you ever figure out an answer?  This may help too - https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/247398/41457