# Maximum likelihood time-series regression with autocorrelation

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation

I'm trying to run a time-series regression model using maximum likelihood estimation to correct for autocorrelation. I have some experience with this, but only in the single-variable case, e.g.,
$$
y_t - \phi y_{t-1} = (1-\phi)\beta_0 + \beta_1(x_t - \phi x_{t-1}) + a_t
$$

So far, this is the only form of the model I've worked with using R. If I wanted to add more variables to this model—for example, a quadratic term or even an interaction term—how would I modify this? Would I do the same as is done for the independent variable here (subtract from it a lagged value multiplied by phi, and multiply the entire quantity by the corresponding value of beta)?

Comment: What do you mean by a "quadratic term or... interaction term" in this context? Do you have multiple time series? Are you waning to fit something like a VAR?

Comment: [This](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/publications/icassp09.pdf) may help for the second variable case, if not for a quadratic.

Answer (score 3):

You can re-write that model as
\begin{align*}
  y_t &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_t + n_t \\
  n_t &= \phi n_{t-1} + a_t
\end{align*}
which is a regression with an AR(1) error.

You can add as many variables as you like to the first equation, and modify the second equation to handle other types of ARMA errors.

Since you are using R, I suggest you use the `Arima` function from the `forecast` package. The regression variables enter via the `xreg` argument, and the ARMA error structure is specified by the `order` argument. Alternatively, use the `auto.arima` function which also takes an `xreg` argument, but it will automatically select the ARMA error structure.